# Issue with setting up docker on WSL in Windows 10 Home

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to setup docker through **WSL**(ubuntu) on **Windows 10 Home** but ran into an issue when trying to use the `docker-compose up` command:

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http://localhost:2375 - is it running?
```

I have the following configuration in my `~/.bashrc` file

```
#Insert new Path for Docker and Alias

PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox"

alias docker=docker.exe

alias docker-machine=docker-machine.exe

// Other code

export DOCKER_HOST='tcp://localhost:2375'
```

docker-machine seems to be running fine as the `docker ps` command shows a list of containers.

From my research, if I were to use **Docker for Windows** (which does not run on Windows Home) ; I need to turn on the “Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS” option in the settings. Since I am using “Docker Toolbox + VirtualBox”, I would like to ask what would be the equivalent?

Please let me know if you require further information.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky because yo need to use two terminals : one in Windows and one in WSL.

What worked for me : I installed docker-machine and virtualbox on Windows. Then I created a virtual machine named default on virtualbox. Then on Windows, with the terminal Git bash for windows,  I ran the following commands :

1. `docker-machine start default` : it starts the virtual machine. Alternatively, you can start it directly on virtualbox
2. `docker-machine env default`: it shows the commands needed to start the linux shell.

Output looks like this

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.101:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="C:\Users\<yourusername>\.docker\machine\machines\default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $("C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\docker-machine\bin\docker-machine.exe" env default)
```

Then you switch to WSL. You can access the terminal by typing ubuntu in the research bar

In /.bashrc, you paste the output (replace with your own output)

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.101:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/mnt/c/Users/<yourusername>/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
```

Note that I changed the DOCKER_CERT_PATH so that it works on a linux environment

Finally, in WSL, run `source /.bashrc`

You can then test your install by running `docker run hello-world`
Remember to keep your virtual machine running.

The following two articles really helped me with the install:

- https://www.sitepoint.com/docker-windows-10-home/
- https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2018/09/20/docker-on-wsl-with-virtualbox-and-docker-machine/